# UIScrollView setContentOffset and setZoom yield wrong position

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

When I log the values, they are all correct but when I set those values to the scrollView, it does not show the desired rect. The zoom scale seems right but the origin seems wrong despite being the right x and y values.

```
CGRect prevRect  =
[self.focusPositions[count-2] CGRectValue];

CGFloat prevZoom =
[self.focusZooms[count-2] floatValue];

self.scrollViewPhoto.contentOffset = CGPointMake(prevRect.origin.x, prevRect.origin.y);
self.scrollViewPhoto.zoomScale     = prevZoom;
```

**EDIT**

```
self.focusPosition
```

contain

```
    NSValue * value =
    [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.scrollViewPhoto.visibleRect];
```

**EDIT2**

`visibleRect` property of the scrollView is:

```
- (CGRect)visibleRect
{
    CGRect visibleRect;
    visibleRect.origin = self.contentOffset;
    visibleRect.size   = self.bounds.size;

    float theScale = 1.0 / self.zoomScale;

    visibleRect.origin.x    *= theScale;
    visibleRect.origin.y    *= theScale;
    visibleRect.size.width  *= theScale;
    visibleRect.size.height *= theScale;

    NSLog(@"visible rect: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(visibleRect));

    return visibleRect;
}
```

Comment: What is `self.focusPositions`?

Comment: self.scrollViewPhoto.visibleRect

Comment: There is no `visibleRect` property for `UIScrollView`

Comment: sorry indeed I forgot I made a category for it see the edit.

Comment: well explaining the problem might hve helped me solved this I have an idea.

Comment: That's good! I think you probably need to do some calculations with that `scale` :)